# When was command line parsing first introduced to shell?

Tags: shell, command-line, history

Per [a discussion in Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44643499#44643499), when was command line parsing (using positional parameters) first introduced to the Unix shell?

And also, was the naming of `$1`, `$2` etc. in any way borrowed from C (for example, from the indexing into C's `argv[]` array)?  Or did that too, like [many other things in the shell syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68C#Algol_68C_and_Unix), come from Algol 68?

Answer (score 2):

When the first [shell](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Unix_shell#/Early_shells) was created in 1971. 
The [man page](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/sh) says:

> When the shell is invoked as a command, it has additional string
>   processing capabilities. Recall that the form in which the shell is
>   invoked is
>
> sh [ name [ arg1 ... [ arg9 ] ] ]
>
> The name is the name of a file which will be read and interpreted. If not given, this
>   subinstance of the shell will continue to read the standard input
>   file. In the file, character sequences of the form "$n", where n is a
>   digit 0, ..., 9, are replaced by the nth argument to the invocation of
>   the shell (arg ). "$0" is replaced by name.

Comment: That rules out a C ancestry then.

Comment: And likely rules out an Algol 68 ancestry as well, because Bourne didn't come to Bell Labs until 1975.

Comment: You may be mistaking Bourne for Thompson, in any event.  (-: